# RegEx to match text after line break

Tags: regex

I have the following input:

> Text1 
>  FirstName LastName (10) 
>  Text2

I need to fetch the full name without the parenthesis. For example:

> User: 
>  John Doe (10) 
>  Email:

**Result: John Doe**

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What language/regex engine are you using?

Comment: Workflow for iOS - https://workflow.is

Comment: You need to get your regex engine working.  Then come back here.

Comment: Tim, It seems this is the version of RegEx that Workflow.is uses: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

Comment: Again, this is strange because the regex given below should be working then.  Can you try putting the regex in single quotes? `'^(.*)\s\(\d+\)$'` ?

Comment: I have uploaded the input text that the RegEx will be using here https://regex101.com/r/nL5cJ7/2

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex on the line containing the first and last name:

```
^(.*)\s\(\d+\)$
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/nL5cJ7/1)

Comment: I'm using a "Match Text" function to scan the text file. I'll give it a shot and let you know the results.

Comment: It did not work as it returns blank. I have to clarify that the word "User": is unique across the whole text file, from there I just need to get the Full Name without the parenthesis.

Comment: The regex is correct.  Can you share a link to the tool you are using?  It is most likely a syntax issue.

Comment: Sure thing, the tool is: Workflow for iOS - www.workflow.is

Comment: Try this: `^(.*) \([0-9]+\)$`

Comment: Tim, same results: blank  :-(

Comment: Both of these answers are correct.  Try breaking up my regex into smaller pieces until you get a match.  Then add the rest back piece by piece.

Comment: Tim, I have updated the Regex101 tester with the actual input text file. The one you posted works fine but when using the input file that my program uses I noticed that there is no match. See: https://regex101.com/r/nL5cJ7/2

Comment: Oh dear.  You need to find a way to run your regex line by line.  It is currently matching the entire file, and this won't work.

Comment: I am successfully using the following RexEx to fetch the email address: [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?   I cannot quite understand why this one works ok.

Answer (score 0):

To match *just* the target you're after, use a look arounds (which don't capture):

```
^(?<=User: \n).*(?=\s+\(\d+\)\s*$)
```

The entire match will be "John Doe".

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Nn87jaFC3E).

Comment: I tried it but it returned blank using the "Match Text" function

Comment: @C4RLOCO I assume you've selected "use regex" in whatever tool you're using?

Comment: That could be a possibility. I was using "User:[/S/s]{1,29} The "Match Text" function returned "John Doe (10) Email:" as of course I am getting at least 29 characters after the line break which as you know, it is not ideal to hardcode the number of characters to get after the word "User:"

Comment: Bohemian, would you mind taking a look at this? The test string is the actual input text: https://regex101.com/r/nL5cJ7/2

Comment: @C4RLOCO I think you mean `^(.*) \([0-9]+\)$` (with brackets escaped)

Comment: Your regex is running in a strange way, and it appears to be trying to match the entire file against one pattern.  This isn't what you want.